# Does early or static binding only apply for methods

Tags: c++, binding

H'llo,The definition for early or static binding in my book was given as this:
 when arguments of methods are resolved during compilation stage it is called static binding or early binding of arguments to the functions.

Does this apply for static methods whose value is linked to the return value of a function and normal functions?

Comment: Static binding isn't about the arguments being resolved at compile time, but rather about the function itself being resolved at compile time.

Comment: If I assign a dynamically created value to the argument of the function does it get resolved at compilation time or runtime?

Comment: What book is this? None of this makes any sense. Arguments don't get "resolved" (whatever that would mean) or bound at all.

Comment: Sumitha arora class xii

Comment: @user3211362 I find it hard to believe that the author would make this kind of mistake. Is your first paragraph an actual quote from the book or did you paraphrase?

Comment: You'll need to clear up stuff - what 'value' of 'static methods' are you referring to? What is the definition of 'late binding' as given by the book?

In general, Methods and Functions do not work all that differently. Just think of Methods as Static Functions *bound* to a `this` context for execution. You could look at how member functions are bound as against static functions, though I daresay that comes later with more coding.

Comment: I just wrote what was written in the book word by word I cant make heads or tails of it , it refuses to elaborate further

Comment: Nope I just wrote it it was from the very 1st page of the 3rd chapter of the 9th edition plus I highlighted it